# Accessing XML DOM child nodes by name

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I want to access the textContent property of an XML object in JavaScript. The root item has several children which also have some children themselves. To get the children on the first level I just iterate through the childNodes Array of the root element. But to get the values of the "grandchilds" I would like to use something like `getElementsByTagName()`, which doesn't work. Currently I just iterate through all children again and check the nodeName property of each to get my values. **Is there a way to get the child object by name?**

XML (**Notice: the XML document I get internally is unformatted, there are no whitespaces, there are no *#text* nodes**):

```
<root>
  <element>
    <child1>content</child1>
    <child2>content</child2>
    <child3>content</child3>
  </element>
  <element>
    <child1>content</child1>
    <child2>content</child2>
    <child3>content</child3>
  </element>
</root>
```

**What I tried so far:**

```
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
for(i = 0; i < xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes.length; i++)
{
  key = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i];
  alert(key.getElementsByTagName('child1')[0].textContent);
}
```

which results in an message box: *undefined* 
and an console error: *TypeError: key.getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined*

Browser: Firefox 26

Maybe it's a problem with the DOM Object, I create it the following way:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: The first child node you are encountering is a text node, and as such does not have any children named `child1` …

Comment: I'm sorry. The XML I use in the project is unformated (without any whitespaces), so there are no "#text" nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the spaces between the nodes are automatically made textNodes. Check if the node at `xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[i]` is a `textNode` (nodeType 3) before you try to find children. I also removed your globals `i` and `key` in this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/GQ8Kd/

```
var node, childNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++)
{
  node = childNodes[i];
  if(node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) console.log(node.getElementsByTagName('child1')[0].textContent);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I checked the node type, it is 1 ELEMENT_NODE

Comment: Try adding `console.log(node.nodeType);` in the loop and you'll see you have 2 text nodes

Comment: no text nodes. Output is 1 for all. Combined it with nodeName to check I iterate over the right nodes. I know that there are text nodes if I have whitespaces in the XML file, but the xml output is not formated. it's just one line of text without whitespaces.

Comment: Can you update my fiddle to break? Cause as far as I can tell it's working fine

Comment: JFYI, it is a bug in the php backend, where the the node I was searching for is not created for the first element - only in the case I used for testing - that's why I always got an error. However, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following obtains the desired value of the child1 nodes for me..

```
var k = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("child1");

for(var i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
{
  console.log(k[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: the .nodeValue property is always undefined, I have to use .textContent to get the node values. Except from this, using the hhildNodes array always works.

Comment: @robin.koch.  I've simplified my answer again.  I'm wondering why this current version would not work for you.  I'm open to hearing your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getElementsByTagName('child1')[0].nodeValue`

Comment: this doesn't work as key.getElementsByTagName('child1')[0] already doesn't exist.