# InnerHTML returns undefined in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following line of code in order to get the content of a XML node:

```
$(this).find("brand")[0].innerHTML
```

(The reason why there is a $(this) is only because i'm in a loop to check every nodes)

The problem is this does not work with IE, it returns undefined.
I also tried different properties like textContent, nodeValue but nothing works in IE.

Does anyone know a solution ? 
Thanks for your time

Comment: could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Well, an XML is not HTML. So it seems to make sense that XML DOM nodes don't have such a property.

Comment: sorry but i can't use jsffidle from where i am due to weird network restrictions

Comment: Are XML node supposed to have an innerHTML property? I don't think so. I think this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407578/accessing-xml-dom-child-nodes-by-name

Comment: Have you tried using `.innerText`?

Comment: @Felix Kling, you are right but i think it's now possible to use innerHTML with XML in Firefox, Chrome. On the other hand i don't know how to do it with IE.

Comment: @FieryA: It may be possible, but that doesn't mean it *should* be ;)

Comment: InnerText returns null

Answer (score 0):

To support custom tag selection in IE8 and below you need to add a sort of reference to the tags before the element is added to the DOM.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script>
    document.createElement('brand');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Unless you do this you cannot use ("brand") as a selector in jQuery in these lower browsers.

Comment: The question is about XML, not HTML. Are you saying this is necessary to be able to parse **XML**?

Comment: I would think it may be necessary because the jQuery selector is being used, you make a fair point and I'm not sure now though!