# How to read an xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

How to get value from a specific child element in XML in Javascript
Here is the XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Data_Speed>
  <Tech ID = "UMTS">
     <Coverage ID="Dense_Urban">
        <DownLoad_Speed>10</DownLoad_Speed>
        <Upload_Speed>20</Upload_Speed>
     </Coverage>
    <Coverage ID="Urban">
        <DownLoad_Speed>30</DownLoad_Speed>
        <Upload_Speed>40</Upload_Speed>
    </Coverage>
    <Coverage ID="SubUrban">
        <DownLoad_Speed>50</DownLoad_Speed>
        <Upload_Speed>60</Upload_Speed>
    </Coverage>
 </Tech>
 <Tech ID = "UMTS900">
    <Coverage ID="Dense_Urban">
      <DownLoad_Speed>11</DownLoad_Speed>
      <Upload_Speed>12</Upload_Speed>
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage ID="Urban">
      <DownLoad_Speed>13</DownLoad_Speed>
      <Upload_Speed>14</Upload_Speed>
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage ID="SubUrban">
      <DownLoad_Speed>15</DownLoad_Speed>
      <Upload_Speed>16</Upload_Speed>
    </Coverage>
 </Tech>
 <Tech ID = "4G800">
    <Coverage ID="Dense_Urban">
     <DownLoad_Speed>30</DownLoad_Speed>
     <Upload_Speed>42</Upload_Speed>
    </Coverage>
   <Coverage ID="Urban">
     <DownLoad_Speed>50</DownLoad_Speed>
     <Upload_Speed>34</Upload_Speed>
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage ID="SubUrban">
    <DownLoad_Speed>45</DownLoad_Speed>
    <Upload_Speed>46</Upload_Speed>
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage ID="Rural">
     <DownLoad_Speed>47</DownLoad_Speed>
     <Upload_Speed>48</Upload_Speed>
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage ID="Variable">
     <DownLoad_Speed>15</DownLoad_Speed>
     <Upload_Speed>52</Upload_Speed>     
   </Coverage>
   <Coverage ID="Outdoor">
     <DownLoad_Speed>25</DownLoad_Speed>
     <Upload_Speed>22</Upload_Speed>
   </Coverage>
</Tech>
</Data_Speed>
```

So how could I get value of DownLoad_Speed> & UpLoad_Speed> element by given Coverage ID Urban> and Tech ID UMTS900>? Say, if I give tech id value = "UMTS900" and coverage id value "Urban", I'd like to have string value dwnload_speed = 13 and Upload_Speed = 14 as result, using Java script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing)

Comment: this can be helpful  --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407578/accessing-xml-dom-child-nodes-by-name